# how to make a process on the server check an entry in a database x seconds after it has been inserted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an application where orders are sent to be processed by waiters. However, a waiter has 30 seconds to confirm that he accepts the order, or it will be passed to the next. How can I check if the IsAccepted column in the orders table was marked as true 30 seconds after the entry was inserted?

I'm looking for a solution as easy as possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest thing is to start a timer to fire 30 seconds after the insert.

See [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) on MSDN for a comparison of the different timer classes.

Just make sure to stop the timer in the tick event handler (or `Elapsed` handler or whatever handler corresponds to the timer you select).